# Array.foreach does not exist on type any[]

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

my problem is when I use the .foreach for an array, it says that property  'foreach' does not exist on type 'any[]'. How should i fix this ?   [image: The foreach becomes red line]

Answer (score 3):

There is forEach

```
productlist.forEach(product => {   });
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, im new to this mobile programming ,

Comment: @ynnhoj24 thats ok :) here is list of methods array has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: friend ? why is it that my value my NaN?

Comment: @ynnhoj24 i dont understand. Can you explain?

Comment: @ynnhoj24 the problem is that the method is named `forEach` but you've written it with a lower-case `e`, `foreach`. JavaScript is case-sensitive

Comment: Maybe next time my friend, the comment section is too short to copy the code . btw thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> Array.foreach does not exist on type any[]

You have a typo.

- Its not `foreach`
- It is `forEach`